# How to pass the data from modal to MYSQL using VueJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I update existing data in a table using a modal to MYSQL using VueJs?

I don't have any idea how to do this and I've read some tutorials but didn't get it, so please help.

Below is my client side code

```
<button class="btn btn-success" v-b-modal="'modal3-' + result.Memb_ID">Edit</button>
<b-modal
            :id="'modal3-' + result.Memb_ID"
            title="Update Details"
            @show="resetModal"
            @hidden="resetModal"
            @ok="editUser()"
          >
            <form ref="form" @submit.stop.prevent="handleSubmit">
              <b-form-group
                :state="nameState"
                label="Member ID"
                label-for="member-input"
                invalid-feedback="Member ID is required"
              >
                <b-form-input
                  id="member-input"
                  v-model="result.Memb_ID"
                  :state="nameState"
                  required
                ></b-form-input>
              </b-form-group>
              <b-form-group
                :state="nameState"
                label="Name"
                label-for="name-input"
                invalid-feedback="First Name is required"
              >
                <b-form-input
                  id="name-input"
                  v-model="result.First_Name"
                  :state="nameState"
                  required
                ></b-form-input>
              </b-form-group>
            </form>
          </b-modal>


 /* Edit User Details. */
    editUser() {
      let insertData = {
        Memb_ID: this.memberModel,
        First_Name: this.firstModel
      };
      axios
        .put("http:/localhost:8080/api/update/user", insertData)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
        });
    }
```

And in my backend using NodeJS

```
router.put('/update/user/:id', function (req, res) {
    let query = "Update Member SET Memb_ID='" + req.body.Memb_ID + "', First_Name='" + req.body.First_Name + "', Middle_Name='" + req.body.Middle_Name + "', Last_Name='" + req.body.Last_Name + "', Address='" + req.body.Address + "', url='" + req.body.url + "' WHERE id=" + req.params.id;
    myDB.query(query, function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send({
            Success: results
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, not really the answer you are looking for but you really need to read up on SQL injection vulnerabilities. This code should not be put in production.

Comment: Hi Joost, I am aware of SQL Injection only a while ago lol. I will rewrite the code and would not deploy in production.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a to write a UpSERT query for Mysql at your backend

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name, age) VALUES(1, "A", 19) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
name="A", age=19
```

You need to check for Params in req.